# Why can't I store 2^64 in an unsigned long on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: c, binary, integer, x86-64, unsigned

Am I missing something? I have run the following:

```
$ uname -a
Linux archlinux 4.16.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 30 12:30:03 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Then in a C program:

```
long l;
printf("sizeof long: %d\n", sizeof l);
```

which output:

```
sizeof long: 8
```

Doesn't this mean that each long contains 64 bits?
But when I execute the following line of code:

```
printf("2^64: %ld\n",  1UL<<64);
```

I get the following warning from gcc:

> sizeof.c:14:29: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]

If I reduce the left bit-shift to 63 instead, then the warning disappears, but it outputs:

> 2^64: -9223372036854775808

This leads me to believe that my assumption of an unsigned long being 64 usable bits is incorrect, but why?

Comment: `%ld` --> `%lu`

Comment: Also, `1UL << 64` places the 1 in the *65th* bit.  The maximum value that can be stored in an unsigned 64-bit integer is 2^64 - 1, since we include 0.

Comment: What is the largest number you can store in a 1-bit data type? Is it 2^1?

Comment: @n.m. seems like it would be 2^1-1 = 1

Comment: Great, so if you can't fit 2^1 in 1 bit, why do you expect to fit 2^64 in 64 bits? Always check the simplest case first.

Comment: @n.m. good point. I will say that I was massively thrown off onto a red-herring of a suspicion by incorrectly displaying the value of 2^63 as a negative number. This caused me to believe that the number was wrapping. Had it displayed as positive, I am sure I would have figured this one out. Doh!

Comment: The total number of distinct values a 64-bit variable can represent is `2^64`.   If that variable is `unsigned`, one of the values it DOES represent is zero.    The maximum value it can represent is therefore `2^64 - 1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number 2^64 requires 65 bits to represent properly in binary - bit #65 is set and the rest are zero.

This is the same reason that unsigned 8-bit numbers can only go up to 255 (2^8 - 1), unsigned 16-bit numbers can only go up to 65535 (2^16 - 1), and so on.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! But why then does 2^63 represent as a negative number?

Comment: @papiro Because you printed it as a signed number. See achal's comment.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` will indeed return you the number of bytes, so yes, it does have 64 bits. 
With `N` binary digits, you can represent a total of `2^N` numbers. If your variable is unsigned, this means `[0, (2^N)-1]` range. If it's a signed number, then the range would have been `[-2^(N-1), +2^(N-1)-1]`. If you'd like to know more about the signed integers, you can read up on "Two's complement".

Moving onto displaying your integer: you tell `printf` how to interpret the variable. If you tell it's a signed integer, then it'll use the most significant bit as sign instead of the value `2^63` (again, check out Two's complement).

This, on the other hand, will print the integer unsigned:

```
printf("%lu", x);
```